# Is it possible to create a custom heatmap in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I'd like to know if it is possible to create a custom heatmap in MATLAB. What I mean by this, is if it's possible to superimpose an image onto MATLAB (the image in this case would be the state I reside in) and produce a heat color in a particular region of the map. If it is, please send me a link with which I can teach myself how to make a script for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Totally possible! Instructions here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/thingspeak/create-heatmap-overlay-image.html

The first step is reading in an image file and showing it on the "graph" that you are forming. This step is detailed by the link as follows:

```
picture = imread('https://www.mathworks.com/help/examples/optim/win64/officeassign_01.png');
[height,width,depth] = size(picture);
imshow(picture);
hold on
```

The next step for you, presuming you already have a state map, is going to be a little trickier: you are going to have to know the x,y positions you would like to map heat onto and the intensity at those points. You are going to need an overlay, either blocks (like a grid) or a smooth map. I assume you'll want some smoothing so you will use a linear interpolation between points. Once you've decided on the x,y,heat intensity mapping, you can do the following:

```
OverlayImage=[];
F = scatteredInterpolant(Y, X, strengthPercent,'linear');
for i = 1:height-1
   for j = 1:width-1
          OverlayImage(i,j) = F(i,j);
   end
end
alpha = (~isnan(OverlayImage))*0.6;
```

To deconstruct what they were doing here a little, they first made an empty overlay. They then made a map that "blended" between points using a linear interpolation. Finally, they made an alpha layer that was a fraction of that intensity.

The final and most important step -- more central to what you are trying to do -- is place the "image" of that heat matrix over the actual image:

```
OverlayImage = imshow( OverlayImage );
% Set the color limits to be relative to the data values
caxis auto  
colormap( OverlayImage.Parent, jet );
colorbar( OverlayImage.Parent );
% Set the AlphaData to be the transparency matrix created earlier
set( OverlayImage, 'AlphaData', alpha );
```

The final line of this sets the transparency of the layer (to alpha) allowing for viewing of the image under the heat map. Really, in combination with the first code block, these are the two steps that should set you on your way. Let me know if you need any help!

Comment: Hi! I have a new question now that I've produced the heatmap. My state picture is massive, and my X and Y coordinates were actual GPS coordinates, so to zero everything out I found the the bottom leftmost corner of my state's GPS coordinates and subtracted them from my X's and Y's. After doing this, my X and Y coordinates are very small. Is my next step to scale the values to the width and length of the map?

Comment: Yep! You’ll need to define a function that takes gps coordinates and returns pixel locations. As a start, maybe think about a function of the form: (gps coordinate / (biggest gps coordinate - littlest gps coordinate) for x or y. That should scale it between 0 and 1. Then try multiplying by the corresponding axis of the image (x pixels wide or y pixels tall)